# Does Not Conform To Protocol Error

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I am making a stock application and I have an issue in my main View Controller. The error message is Type "ViewController" does not conform to protocol 'AutocompleteDelegate'. If anyone knows how to solve this it would be much appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
extension ViewController:AutocompleteDelegate{
func autoCompleteTextField() -> UITextField {
    return self.textInput
}
func autoCompleteThreshold(textField: UITextField) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func autoCompleteHeight() -> CGFloat {
    return CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) / 3.0
}


func didSelectItem(item: AutocompletableOption) {
    var outPut=""
    for char in item.text.characters {
        if (char >= "A" && char <= "z"){
            outPut.append(char)
        }
        else{
            break
        }
    }

    self.textInput.text = outPut
}

}
```

Comment: Show the declaration of `AutocompleteDelegate`.

Comment: All I did was import CCAutoComplete

Comment: The Very first line is where I'm getting my error.

Comment: @LucMollard You have to implement all AutocompleteDelegate methods

Comment: Make sure , you have to implement all the abstract methods of protocol AutocompleteDelegate and also you have to confirms the protocol too..

Comment: Use AppCode and have it generate all necessary implementations (as stubs).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing implementation for following method

```
func autoCompleteItemsForSearchTerm(term: String) -> [AutocompletableOption]
```

Any conforming type that conforms to AutocompleteDelegate, requires to have following instance methods

```
func autoCompleteTextField() -> UITextField

func autoCompleteThreshold(textField: UITextField) -> Int

func autoCompleteItemsForSearchTerm(term: String) -> [AutocompletableOption]

func autoCompleteHeight() -> CGFloat

func didSelectItem(item: AutocompletableOption) -> Void
```

You already implemented the other 4 methods, just need to have `autoCompleteItemsForSearchTerm` implementation as well.